# Why DateTimeZone.getDefault() does not get updated when Zone in Android is changed

Tags: java, android, datetime, timezone, jodatime

I reviewed many questions related to TimeZones on Stackoverflow, but I could not find the one to the problem I am struggling with:

- Why doesn't Joda's `DateTimeZone.getDefault()` return updated timezone on TZ change (after resuming an application?). **`TimeZone.getDefault()` seems to be working just fine**.
- Should I use `DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault())` to get up to date Joda's `DateTimeZone` object?

**Here is how to replicate:**

1. Start app that prints both `DateTimeZone.getDefault()` and `TimeZone.getDefault()`:

> 09-15 16:46:59.512 14961-14961/com.example.android.whatever D/TimeZone:
>   **DateTimeZone.getDefault()=Europe/London;** **TimeZone.getDefault()=libcore.util.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/London"**,...]

2. Go to settings -> change Timezone to PDT.
3. Go back to Application that prints stuff (e.g. in onResume()):

> 09-15 08:49:24.727 14961-14961/com.example.android.whatever
>   D/TimeZone: **DateTimeZone.getDefault()=Europe/London;**
>   **TimeZone.getDefault()libcore.util.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles"**,...]

4. At this stage I can be rotating the App. The `DateTimeZone.getDefault()` will be stuck.
5. Only after application onRestart - the value will be correct.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joda-Time caches the default timezone.

If you run this code (in my JVM, the default timezone is `America/Sao_Paulo`):

```
System.out.println("JVM default=" + TimeZone.getDefault().getID()); // America/Sao_Paulo
DateTimeZone t1 = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println("Joda Default=" + t1); // America/Sao_Paulo

// setting the default timezone to London
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
System.out.println("JVM default=" + TimeZone.getDefault().getID()); // Europe/London
DateTimeZone t2 = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println("Joda Default=" + t2); // America/Sao_Paulo
System.out.println(t1 == t2);  // true
```

The output will be:

> JVM default=America/Sao_Paulo
>   Joda Default=America/Sao_Paulo
>   JVM default=Europe/London
>   Joda Default=America/Sao_Paulo
>   true

Also note that `t1 == t2` returns `true`, which means they are exactly the same instance.

To set Joda's default timezone after changing the JVM default, you must set it in `DateTimeZone` too:

```
// change Joda's default timezone to be the same as the JVM's
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()));
DateTimeZone t3 = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println("Joda Default=" + t3); // Europe/London
System.out.println(t1 == t3); // false
```

This outputs:

> Joda Default=Europe/London
>   false

After restarting everything, the cache disappears and Joda-Time gets the new default when first called.

Answer (score 3):

You should not directly use Joda-Time but **better use the library of Daniel Lew** ([JodaTimeAndroid](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) - a thin wrapper around Joda-Time) because

- it has better performance characteristics when loading the tz data on Android
- it has a suitable broadcast-receiver to track changes of the [system timezone](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android/blob/master/library/src/main/java/net/danlew/android/joda/TimeZoneChangedReceiver.java).